# Celery group as callback

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery task which returns a list. Following this, I would like each element of the list to be sent to a 2 task chain. As far as I can see this is like the reverse of a `chord`. I.e. instead of having a single task as a callback for a `group`, I want a `group` of tasks as a callback for a single task.

Something like:
`group(chain(validate.s(i) | run.s(i))() for i in results_from_first_task)`

Is there a way to automatically execute this group after the first task has finished?

As a simplified example, Imagine a simple task which returns a list of files:

```
@app.task()
def list_files(pattern):
  return glob.glob(pattern)
```

And another couple of tasks which perform an action on a single file:

```
@app.task()
def validate(path):
    return my_validation_function(path)

@app.task()
def run(path):
    return my_run_function(path)
```

I want `validate` and `run` to be executed for each entry from the result of `list_files`.

Comment: even i am trying to do the same thing, a group a running some function for each value from a list and a group b where each function gets result from a corresponding task in a, i guess the only option is to explicitly fire subtask from a

Answer (score 1):

You can use celery signals to queue up your tasks.

```
from celery.signals import task_success


@task_success.connect()
def task_success_handler(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    result = kwargs['result']
    for file in result:
        validate.apply_async(file)
        run.apply_async(file)
```

Alternatively, you can create an intermediate task and use it to queue up other tasks

```
@app.task()
def process(result):
    for file in result:
        validate.apply_async(file)
        run.apply_async(file)
```

Now you can use this task in your group.